XLA PJRT plugin on Mac reveals only 4 CPUs
On my MacOS M3, I have compiled the pjrt_c_api_cpu_plugin.so and I'm using it with JAX.
My Macbook has 12 CPUs but with a simple python script "jax.devices()" the pjrt plugin reveals just 4 cpus.
Can you tell me why ?
